# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException while sending request through Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am trying to send a JSON request to a secure REST webservice using a keystore file and I am using Jersey API. Below is the snippet of my code

```
SslConfigurator sslConfigurator = SslConfigurator.newInstance().trustStoreFile("C:\\Users\\******\\test.keystore").trustStorePassword("password");
SSLContext sslContext = sslConfigurator.createSSLContext();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build();
WebTarget target = client.target("https://hostname:portnumber").path("resourse/methodname/v1");

Form form = new Form();
form.param("key1", "value1");
form.param("key2", "value2");

Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE));
System.out.println(response);
```

But I am getting the following exception on the last but one line.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Already connected
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:264)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
at TestMain.main(TestMain.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnection.java:3014)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestProperty(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.setOutboundHeaders(HttpUrlConnector.java:421)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.access$100(HttpUrlConnector.java:96)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$4.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:384)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:194)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:262)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.commitStream(OutboundMessageContext.java:816)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:545)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
... 10 more
```

Answer (score 6):

It is actually a bug in jersey that the error message in the exception is basically wrong. Please see [SSLHandshakeException masked by useless IllegalStateException: Already connected](https://github.com/gondor/openstack4j/issues/78)

So basically, it means that there is a problem in SSL handshaking between the server and client.

One of the causes of the exception is related to this: [Jersey API Doc - 5.9. Securing a Client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html)

> ... ClientBuilder also offers a method for defining a custom HostnameVerifier implementation. HostnameVerifier implementations are invoked when default host URL verification fails.
>
> Important
>
> A behaviour of HostnameVerifier is dependent on an http client
> implementation. HttpUrlConnector and ApacheConnector work properly,
> that means that after the unsuccessful URL verification
> HostnameVerifier is called and by means of it is possible to
> revalidate URL using a custom implementation of HostnameVerifier and
> go on in a handskahe processing. JettyConnector and GrizzlyConnector
> provide only host URL verification and throw a CertificateException
> without any possibility to use custom HostnameVerifier. Moreover, in
> case of JettyConnector there is a property
> JettyClientProperties.ENABLE_SSL_HOSTNAME_VERIFICATION to disable an
> entire host URL verification mechanism in a handshake.

If you are using Grizzly, you can't turn it off, but there is a workaround. It is to set a customized HostnameVerifier that the verify() always returns true in the client configuration:

```
        Client c = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){
              @Override
              public boolean verify(String paramString, SSLSession paramSSLSession) {
               return true;
             }
        }).build();
```